# Angular: Order html elements depending on scope varaible

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two divs that I want to show on the page. The order of the two divs depends on the value of a variable on the scope.

The trivial way of doing this is by repeating the divs code twice in the page, each time in a different order:

```
<div class="option 1" ng-if="value">
  <div class="div 1">
    <p>"this is the content for div 1"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div 2">
    <p>"this is the content for div 2"</p>        
  </div>
</div>

<div class="option 2" ng-if="!value">
  <div class="div 2">
    <p>"this is the content for div 2"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div 1">
    <p>"this is the content for div 1"</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there another way to do this, without repeating the code?

Comment: If you have only 2 divs inside, you can push/pull div using CSS

Comment: refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not support IE9 I guess you can use the flexbox order CSS property with a conditional class.

```
<div class="main">
  <div ng-class="{after: !value}">this is the content for div 1</div>
  <div class="fixed">this is the content for div 2</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.main { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.fixed { order: 2; }
.after { order: 3; }
```

See the flexbox order in action: https://jsfiddle.net/a6eaov63/2/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** You can move each `<div>` to external file and include it in proper order depending on `value`.

```
<ng-include src="value ? 'div1.html' : 'div2.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="value ? 'div2.html' : 'div1.html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: The difference between the divs is their content. The name of the class what just for the sake of example

Comment: @Asher It wasn't clear from your question. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('orderDivs', [])
  .controller('orderController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //$scope.variable = true; //uncomment this line to reverse the div .. 
    $scope.divList = [{'div':'option 1','condition':'true', 'content':'THIS IS DIV 1111'},{'div':'option 2','condition':'false', 'content':'THIS IS DIV 2222'}]
      if ($scope.variable){
        $scope.divList = $scope.divList.reverse();
      } 
      $scope.changeOrder = function(){
        $scope.divList = $scope.divList.reverse();
      }
    }]);
})(window.angular);



<!-- in views -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="orderDivs">
  <div ng-controller="orderController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="changeOrder()" ng-model="variable"/>
    <div ng-repeat="opt in divList">
      <div class="option" ng-model="opt.div" ng-if="opt.condition">
        <div>
          {{opt.content}}    
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but couldn't get it to work. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5zc6zzUpTQcJ4nTmTlza?p=preview). Can you edit it so that it works?

Comment: hi, i have edited the file above. You have to set the $scope.variable. If you would want to set the scope.variable through the checkbox, then you got to add a ng-click function to the same.

Comment: I have edited the file(above.). Have added an ng-click to reverse the orders of the DIV. The above code works.

Comment: The reason I don't really like your solution is that in a case where the content of the div is some complex html (which is my real case), you will have to add a lot of html into the controller. Still you answer works so I will upvote it.